# Selector where table td: contains null in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a table to display a somewhat 'timetable':

```
+------------------------------------------+                     KEY:
|NAME 00:00  00:20  00:40  01:00  01:20 etc            XXXXXXX is actually 'itemA'
|item XXXXXXXXXXXX  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY                YYYYYYY is actually 'itemAB'
|item YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY  XXXXXXXXXXXX                ZZZZZZZ is actually 'itemABC'
|item ------------  ZZZZZZZZZZZZ  XXXXX                ------- is actually null/blank
```

which is made up using:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>NAME</th><th>00:00</th><th>00:20</th><th>00:40</th><th>01:00</th><th>01:20</th><th>etc</th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row1">
      <th>item</th>
      <td colspan="2">itemA</td>
      <td colspan="3">itemAB</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>item</th>
      <td colspan="3">itemAB</td>
      <td colspan="2">itemA</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>item</th>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2">itemABC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am then using the script to create a colour co-ordination for each item:

```
<script>
    $("#row1 td:contains('itemA')").css("background-color", "lightBlue");
    $("#row1 td:contains('itemAB')").css("background-color", "yellow");
    $("#row1 td:contains('itemABC')").css("background-color", "lightGreen");
    $("#row1 td:contains('')").css("background-color", "Black");
</script>
```

However, when this is executed, ALL cells are coloured black (I only want black to appear when cell in this table is empty, no other reason).

this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/w0bga878/) shows what I want it to be like. (excluding the use of making empty cells black in this table)

this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/w0bga878/1/) shows what i'm getting if i include the last line of my script

---

So with whole table: [this will be a design for end result](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/w0bga878/3/), obviously without hard coding the background color.

---

**EDIT**

So, I've had plenty of guidance on the pseudo element `:empty`, which has been very helpful.

However, it doesn't quite work the way i expected it to, (as the last column 'etc' is, in my opinion, also 'empty', but never gets filled black:

So I end up with:

```
+------------------------------+
|    |    |    |    |    |ETC  |                      
+------------------------------+
|    |    itemA     |  B |                 
+------------------------+
|    |    itemB     |  A |       <-- this section here is 'part' of the table        
+------------------------+           but never is physically 'defined' using a <td> 
|    |?|?|?|?|?| C  ||?|?|           tag      
+------------------------+
       ^                      ^          
       |                      |
       |                       \
      black background           is there a way of making this 'undefined'
      (as wanted)                section also appear as being ':empty'
                                 and hence have a 'background: black'
```

As shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/w0bga878/15/)

Comment: Put the last one first.

Comment: Remember, `:contains` looks for a substring match, not an exact match of the whole contents. So everything contains `''`.

Comment: @jbutler483 that cannot be done. You need to have a cell so that you can give it some color. So either you change the colspan so that all rows are of same width or add extra td elements to fill up the gap.

Comment: @Barmar, as a question is there a way of getting an exact match?

Comment: @lsp i'm currently using a `<td colspan="58"></td>` but it seems a bit like a hack tbh. Esp when IMHO a table is rectangular

Comment: You can use `.filter`, then the function can use `$(this).text() == ''`.

Comment: @Barmar that could be a better approach anyway. Will have a quick look now cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` psuedo selector to find elements which have no content:

```
$("#row1 td:empty").css("background-color", "black");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w0bga878/5/)

Note that I amended the fiddle to work on all rows of the table so you can see all the states.

---

To achieve what you require in your update you could set a default background colour on the `table` element, and then set the `td` and `th` to have the normal background colour. You would need to remove the borders though, otherwise the table background will show through. This can be worked around by using some padding to increase the gutters between the cells. Something like this:

```css
table {
    background-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th, 
table td {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w0bga878/17/)

Comment: thank you Rory. Would there be a way of adding this effect to any 'unddefined' cells (i.e. the bottom last 'part' of the table, that has no 'td' defined), or the whole 'etc' column to be black since it's cells are undefined

Comment: @jbutler483 Can you explain in detail what you meant exactly in the above comment so that i might help you?

Comment: @jbutler483 unfortunately there is no way to do that as there are no cells in that space.

Comment: @lsp please see edit. Rory, I don't suppose something like 'make background black as default for all apart from first row and first column' wouldn't make it black, or something similar to a container div or something?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I've updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

**:empty** pseudo selector will select empty td elements from the selected row. You can refer this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0bga878/9/).

```
$("#row1 td:empty").css("background-color", "Black")
```

Hope it is clear enough 1

Answer (score 1):

simple just move the last line to fist line

```
 $("#row1 td:contains('')").css("background-color", "Black");
    $("#row1 td:contains('itemA')").css("background-color", "lightBlue");
    $("#row1 td:contains('itemAB')").css("background-color", "yellow");
    $("#row1 td:contains('itemABC')").css("background-color", "lightGreen");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w0bga878/6/)**

NOTE: contains('') is accrued all nodes ,You have to use @Rory McCrossan Post  ,that is good

Comment: I tried this with my project, but the issue is with my bad design (i think), where the table continues, I don't actually define the "td's" after the last input (i.e. the last 'slot' might be 15:00-15:20, and I may not continue adding these 'td's' for the rest of the day

Answer (score 1):

Set a black background on all cells first, then look for the 'special' ones

```
$("#row1 td").css("background-color", "Black");        
$("#row1 td:contains('itemA')").css("background-color", "lightBlue");
$("#row1 td:contains('itemAB')").css("background-color", "yellow");
$("#row1 td:contains('itemABC')").css("background-color", "lightGreen");
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```
$("#row1 td:empty").css("background-color", "black");
```